# cannot remove the last element from linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I cannot remove the last element from linked list, the problem is that when I remove it the only node I've is the previus one(before the last one). Here is my code:

```
node *remove_node(int d, node *lst){
    node *prev;
    node *temp = lst;
    if(temp->data == d){
        if(temp->next != NULL){
            node *sec_temp = temp;
            temp = temp->next;
            free(sec_temp);
            return temp;
        }
        else{
            free(temp);
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    while(temp != NULL && temp->data != d){
        prev = temp;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    if(temp == NULL){return lst;}
    //Here is the problem
    if(temp->next == NULL){
        prev->next = NULL;
        free(temp);
        return prev;
    }
    //end
    else {
        prev->next = temp->next;
        free(temp);
        return prev;
    }
}
int main(){
    node *lst = NULL;
    lst = new_node(1, lst);
    lst = new_node(2, lst);
    lst = new_node(3, lst);
    lst = new_node(4, lst);
    lst = remove_node(1, lst);
    print(lst);// this will print the list, works perfect
    return 0;
}
```

When I remove 1(which is the last element in the list), then only 2 is printed, in every other case everything works perfect(if I remove 2 or 3 or 4 I don't have any problems.).
Any ideas what may couse the problem ?

Comment: You're not updating the next pointers.  You cannot simply free a node in the middle of the list as you are doing, since a next pointer now points to a freed node.

Comment: I don't get what you mean, this is the case where the node I have to remove is the last, so I set the previues element from the list to point to NULL(end of the list) and then I free the node which should be removed(the last node).

Comment: Hint: if there is only one node on the list, this node will also be the last. And the first.

Comment: You're asking us to put faith that `new_node` actually sets `next` to NULL on the initial insert. And your remove code is destined for the wrecking ball if the target node is *not* in the list, or the first and only node is the one being deleted, which dangles a `temp` pointer and invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: 1. Yes new_node sets next to NULL as I said everything except this works perfectly.
2. If the node is the first(or the only) node it will enter in the first if condition and get removed, the function will return. 
however I don't check anywhere if the node really exists.

Comment: I've add this line after the while loop which is searching for the element:
if(temp == NULL){return lst;} 
However the problem is still here

Comment: Then update the code posted, and btw, [this is what you're trying to do](http://pastebin.com/nNEJ3Vb0).

Comment: This is working perfectly, thank you. Give this as answer so I can give you "best answer".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making this much more complicated than it needs to be. There are several methods for deleting a node in forward linked, null-terminated linked list. You can do it using two pointers (a previous and current pointer), which is what you appear to be attempting. Stop coding until you understand the actual algorithm:

```
node *remove_node(int d, node *lst)
{
    node *prev = NULL, *cur = lst;

    while (cur && cur->data != d)
    {
        prev = cur; 
        cur = cur->next;
    }

    if (cur)
    {
        if (!prev) // head node was the match
            lst = lst->next;
        else
            prev->next = cur->next;
        free(cur);
    }
    return lst;
}
```

**How It Works**

Initially we have two pointers, `prev` which points to the previous node in the list to the current test-node and is initially NULL, and `cur`, the current node we're testing, which is initially the list head.

Walk the list one node at a time, each time testing whether we have (a) not yet reached the end of the list (`cur != NULL`) and (b) found a node that matches our target data (`cur->data == d`). We break the loop accordingly. Once the loop breaks, `cur` either refers to the node to be deleted or is NULL, meaning we found no match.

The value of `prev` is only important when `cur` is non-NULL, meaning we found a match. If we found a match and `prev == NULL` we *must* be on the head node, otherwise `prev` refers to a node who's `next` pointer needs to link to the `cur->next` pointer to splice the list and remove our victim before deletion.

That really is all there is to it. I *strongly* suggest you hand-walk a deletion operation through the debugger and look at what the pointers address along the way. Debuggers aren't just for finding broken things. They're a wonderful tool for helping to understand better how code works (because you get to actually "see" it working).

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you returns the `prev` pointer which points to the element before the removed one, but the beginning of the list remains the `lst`pointer in reality. Next in the `main` method you use the returned pointer in the printing method therefore you prints only this last element.